# Webpack 2 : You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have checked my config and packages multiple times and cannot figure out whats up. Seems webpack is ignoring my babelrc file but I've also tried using the `presets` option in my config and still cant get it to transpile React. Doing it from the command line with babel cli works fine:

***webpack.config.js***

```
var path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './frontend/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js || jsx)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend')
            }
        ],
    }
};



module.exports = config;
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],

  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./frontend"],
      "alias": {
        "actions": "actions",
        "components": "components",
        "reducers": "reducers",
        "stores": "stores",
        "utils": "utils"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./frontend/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "fetchr": "^0.5.36",
    "fluxible": "^1.2.0",
    "fluxible-action-utils": "0.2.4",
    "fluxible-addons-react": "0.2.8",
    "fluxible-reducer-store": "^0.1.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "jest": "^18.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\.(js || jsx)$/
```

is not how regular expressions work. You mean

```
/\.(js|jsx)$/
```

Comment: Wow, I'm retarded. Thats what I get for copy and pasting regex

Comment: this is a little bit more concise:  /\.jsx?$/

Comment: Yup, all kinds of options. I just kept it similar to the original.